# Internet Explorer 8 - Back Button Stops Working

Tags: internet-explorer-8

I've been trying to support an issue with IE8 where when a user clicks the back button, then the forward button, the back button becomes disabled.  If you google for "IE8 back button stops working" you'll see that I am not alone.  No one out there has come up with a solution for this yet.  Short of having to reinstall IE8 on every machine(many, many machines) I was hoping ask and find a solution.  Thanks!

Edit:

I've tried running IE8 without add-ons and restored the settings of the browswer and neither worked.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried resetting IE8?

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Reset-Internet-Explorer-settings

.

Comment: I sure did and it didn't work.  Someone suggested running "repair" on IE but I don't know where to go to do that.

Comment: More suggestions here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/936213